# Nodes near coords gives Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, nodes-near-coords

I have the following example of a graph. I want to place the items in the table "Restart" next to the nodes. Everything works until I add "nodes near coords", I get a bunch of errors saying "Undefined Control Sequence \end {axis}" and "Missing control sequence inserted \end{axis}"

I'm using the latest pgfplogs (v1.8), the wierd part is that when I enable the nodes near coords option I do get errors but my graph also draws correctly.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    % If I remove nodes near coords line everything works, if I enable it, I get errors
        nodes near coords={\label},
        cycle list name=exotic, 
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Restart} \as \label},  
        every node near coord/.append style={
            anchor=mid west,
            xshift=1pt,
            yshift=5pt,
            font={\footnotesize}
        },
        clip mode=individual,
        ylabel={Error (m)}, 
        xlabel={Standard Deviation (m)},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        xlabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        yticklabel/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
        xticklabel/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
        ymax=11,
        ymin=-1,
        symbolic x coords={0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00, 1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00, 3.50, 4.00, 4.50, 5.00},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style={
        inner sep=2pt,
            xshift=1.5pt,
            anchor=north east,
            rotate=45
        },
        x axis line style={-},      
    ]
    \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=+5}

    \addplot+[dashed, mark options=solid,
        /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
            x dir=none,
            y dir=both,
            error bar style={thin,solid},
            y explicit,    
        ]
    table [x={Standard Deviation (m)},y={Error (m)}, y error=Variance, col sep=comma] {
Restart,{Standard Deviation (m)},{Error (m)},Variance
4,0.10,9.580479722,0.004650518
3,0.20,7.041733905,0.000561627
4,0.50,1.07983849,0.030414248
2,0.75,0.058386362,0.025176577
3,1.00,0.532316937,0.059721487
3,1.25,5.86951615,0.360786607
3,1.50,0.586363552,0.082407842
2,1.75,9.873261494,0.029932573
3,2.00,6.352042095,1.410836942
0,2.50,0.45595227,0.157863302
1,3.00,0.251621273,0.150290522
0,3.50,0.274931276,0.173965793
0,4.00,0.198035166,0.176157261
0,4.50,0.404109133,0.29203061
0,5.00,0.237515925,0.476506476
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the error message in the log that I get, it keeps repeating for a while (I think):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformpointmeta ...@trafo 
                                                  {\pgfplotspointmeta }\let ...
l.68     \end{axis}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no Y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 9 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 8 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 9 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.68     \end{axis}

Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformpointmeta ...@trafo 
                                                  {\pgfplotspointmeta }\let ...
l.68     \end{axis}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no Y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 9 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 8 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 9 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.68     \end{axis}
```

Comment: I've protected the spaces in the column names and removed the col sep=tab. I don't have access to TeX right now but apparently clip mode is interfering otherwise it compiles fine. https://www.writelatex.com/191875qwdxwq they probably have 1.7 on writeLaTeX server though

Comment: I tried your solution and it still gives me the same errors, thanks :)

Comment: It works fine for me (after I replace the spaces with tabs, they get lost when posting on Stackexchange). What PGFPlots version are you using?

Comment: The latest version (v1.8 unstable)

Comment: You might be experiencing problems caused by the *unstable* version (which has a recent, rarely tested change in that area).

Comment: How can I use the v1.8 stable then? Just use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` or something else?

Comment: Oke I tried changing to versions 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4 and they all give me the same error..

Answer (score 2):

Oke solved the problem,

I was using the v1.8 unstable package, after installing the v1.8 stable package I didn't have any error at all.

I hope this can help anybody else (but one should never install beta packages).

Regards,